# NSOpenPanel doesn't show when i call runModal

Tags: entitlements, nsopenpanel

Hello Because I spent hours looking for a solution and found none, and discovered the error I though I'd go out and post it.

I created an NSOpenPanel in the same way everyone is creating it set the file types that it accepts, and gave it a call to runModal, and the program froze for about 15 seconds and then continued operation as if the modal had been cancelled. The problem was that I was using entitlements with my application, and when app sandboxing I needed to set user file access to read write in order for it to work. once i set that up in my project settings, i ran the program again and was able to use the NSOpenPanel.  good luck all.

Comment: are you able to found solution for this? I am getting same problem..